# Position of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I change the length of nodes in TikZ?

```
\documentclass[border=0.9cm]{standalone}
 
% More defined colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,
    fill=Goldenrod,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm,
]  (controller) {$C(s)$};
 
\node [draw,
    fill=SeaGreen, 
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    below right= 0.5cm and -2cm of controller
]  (sensor) {$G(s)$};

        
\draw[-stealth] (controller.east) -| (sensor.east)
 node[midway,above]{$u$};

\draw[-stealth] (sensor.west) |- (controller.west)
 node[midway,above]{$u$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to divide those lines from those shapes? I want something like this
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\draw[-stealth] (controller.east) -- +(0.5,0) |- node[pos=0.25,right]{$u$} (sensor.east);
\draw[-stealth] (sensor.west) -- +(-0.5,0) |- node[pos=0.25,left]{$u$} (controller.west);
```

`+(0.5,0)` designates a new coordinate relative to the preceding point, `0.5` units to the right. From there you can go down (`|`) and left (`-`) to the target coordinate.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.9cm]{standalone}
 
% More defined colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,
    fill=Goldenrod,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm,
]  (controller) {$C(s)$};
 
\node [draw,
    fill=SeaGreen, 
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    below right= 0.5cm and -2cm of controller
]  (sensor) {$G(s)$};

        
\draw[-stealth] (controller.east) -- +(0.5,0) |- node[pos=0.25,right]{$u$} (sensor.east);
\draw[-stealth] (sensor.west) -- +(-0.5,0) |- node[pos=0.25,left]{$u$} (controller.west);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```